# Why is runlevel 0:halt or runlevel6: reboot necessary

Tags: linux, init, runlevel

Why would you ever need to set the /etc/inittab to RL 0 or 6? Wouldn't you want your system to come back up after the reboot?

Comment: Do you mean why would you want to set the _default_ runlevel to 0 or 6?  Because yes, that would be a Very Bad Idea other than the potential case of a system you have decommissioned but have not yet removed from a datacenter, and do not ever want online.  I cannot think of a good use-case for RL6 other than perhaps stress-testing power supplies and PDUs.

Comment: Only time I've heard of that really being done was a friend who sat the RHCE exam.  Default config of the broken machine he was to fix as part of the test had the default set to 0 ...

Comment: Ok. That makes sense. Most things run on RL3 and 5 anyways.

Comment: Why do you think there would ever be a need to do that?

Answer (score 2):

init 0 actually is a symlink to the init 6 script because it's similar
init 6 reboots the system except when invoked as init 0 in which case it halts the system, (Powered Off, no activity, can be safely powered down)

#### Emergency reboot or shutdown with magic commands

Force an immediate reboot:

```
echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
echo b > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```

Shut the machine down entirely: (Very rarely used)

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/kernel/sysrq
 echo o > /proc/sysrq-trigger
```